# How can I solve the following equation analytically for t: $t=a(e^t+b)$?

Tags: exponential-function, nonlinear-system

I need to solve $t=a(e^t+b)$ analytically for $t$ knowing that $a$, $b$ are constants, any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean analytically*?

Comment: I doubt there is an analytic solution in terms of elementary functions.  You are asking to find a point of intersection between the exponential curve $y=e^t$ and a line $y = (t/a) - b$.  Depending on the values of $a,b$ there might be no solution, one solution, or two solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see Wikipedia article on [Lambert $W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

\begin{align}t = a(e^t+b) &\implies t = ae^t+ab\\
&\implies t -ab = ae^t\\
&\implies (t-ab)e^{ab-t} = ae^{ab}\\
&\implies (ab-t)e^{ab-t} = -ae^{ab}\\
&\implies ab-t = W(-ae^{ab})\\
&\implies t = ab-W(-ae^{ab})\end{align}

Comment: Basically "define a solution" :P

Comment: @CompuChip How else would you expect it to come about?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll see Lambert W function